# Display NotifyOSD notification from a log file

Tags: bash, notification, notify-osd, snort

I am using Snort for a real-time intrusion detection system (IDS), my desire is for real-time system notifications each time a new log is written to the log file. So, NotifyOSD will display a notification of the log for each log written. I understand [using a patched NotifyOSD](https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-the-notification-bubble-in-ubuntu-raring/) I can use `notify-send "$snort.log"`.

[image: NotifyOSD]

However, this will print all lines within the log file, repeatedly. I could use `rsyslog` or `rsync` and write the newest line to a temporary file, which would be cleared after each `watch` command ran, and with `watch` delay the output of `notify-send "$temp.snort.log`. Although I feel this is gratuitous, furthermore the output would still need sanitising.

Is there a better way to achieve the real-time IDS notifications with NotifyOSD, than:

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n1 notify-send "$temp.snort.log"
truncate -s 0 "$temp.snort.log"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
tail -f "$temp.snort.log" | xargs -d '\n' -L1 notify-send --
```

`tail -f` keeps the file open and prints new lines as they are added to the file. `xargs` then reads each line and runs `notify-send` on it. The `--` signals end of options to `notify-send`, so that a line beginning with `-` isn't accidentally considered as an option.